# How to Detect if On Homepage to hide a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

If I have a static HTML homepage, is there a way of embedding some Javascript to see if I am on the home page? What I want to do is if a user is not on the homepage, display a "home" button on my navigation bar. So once I know if he's on the homepage I can use an if-else statement. Not familiar on how to do this in Javascript. I would do this in PHP, but due to restrictions on the project, I am not allowed to use PHP. This site is pure HTML pages.

The reason I need Javascript to detect the page, is because all of the pages, including the homepage are to be the same template (again, not my decision). If it wasn't for this I could create a template for every page but homepage. So that leaves me with the problem.

My current thought is to use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if(sPage != "index.html"){
$turnonhomelink=true;
}
else{
$turnonhomelink=false;
}
</script>
```

And then for the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ($turnonhomelink==true){
echo '<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>';
}
else{
//echo nada
}
</script>
```

Besides the normal "this won't work if Javascript isn't on", is there anything I am missing?

The line I am most concerned about is this: `if(sPage != "index.html")`
Important to note is that this site is only 1 layer deep link-wise (all HTML pages in one directory), but is this the proper way of comparing strings in Javascript?

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and PHP willy-nilly.

Comment: I'd suggest using `sPage = sPath.split('/').pop()` (as `pop()` has a better cross-browser implementation than `lastIndexOf()`.

Comment: @Matt I corrected my code a second ago, am I still mixing?

Comment: @David not familiar with pop(), do I need to change lines other than the ones I currently have (is return different?)

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN reference for `pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

Comment: echo is not a javascript function. in javascript, variables typically do not start with "$", although if using jQuery, this could be an indication that this is a jQuery wrapped element. typically you would want to declare a variable using the `var` keyword before using it, otherwise it will be made a global variable. creating variables in the global scope is not ideal. using a namespace is suggested. mixing your javascript and html source in the same file is not ideal. using a script tag with a src attribute, or using an AMD loader is recommended.

Comment: @dqhendricks how do you do an echo in Javascript then? Have been doing solid backend PHP for far too long now.

Comment: @ChrisMirno you shouldn't really ever need to do an echo in javascript. if you ever do, you may want to reconsider the design of what you are doing. if you must however, you would use `window.print()`. you will want to look into using jQuery or similar to make your life easier as well. typically you would have all of your javascript in a separate file, and it would reference ids and classes of elements within your page to bind UI events and whatnot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May i suggest that absolutly no javascriptr is required to achieve this. There are plenty of ways to do this with just css. Especially if you are on a static html page. The easy way would be to add a id to your body tag to indicate you are on the hompegae. Then add some css to make the home button invisble when on this page. Somethiong like this:

HTML:

```
<body id="homepage">
...
   <li id='home-button'>
      <a href='/index.htm'>Home</a>
   </li>
...
```

CSS:

```
#homepage #home-button {
  display: none;
}
```

This way the visistors with js disabled get the same experience as the normal visitors...

Comment: Thats true. Didn't think of that. That is alot more ideal than using Javascript.

Comment: I take that back. Since they are all the same template (Even the homepage) I can't do that unfortunately.

Comment: there is bound to be a way to this this with css. Could you perhaps post the template code on jsfiddle or something, perhaps i can make a sugestions that fits your case.

Comment: it's a Dreamweaver template, of which the navigation bar is an uneditable region (meaning that it is the same on all pages and is defined by template).

Comment: It has been quiet a while since i used dreamweaver, but if i remember well you can actualy define more editable regions on one page (how else about the pagetitle, can't be the same on every page) even just for the id attribute of the body. I would suggest doing some research on this,as i do believe this is the better solution

Comment: I'll look into doing this. I know I can make multiple regions, but the ideal solution would require the end-users not to have to paste CSS everytime they make a new page. I'll look into this w/DW because I do believe this is the best solution thus far.

Comment: really quick question though. Why wouldn't I put the `id` on the `<li>` instead, since the button in my example is a list element?

Comment: id is indeed the best choice, i was just giving a quick example and did not notice the link was in an id (as it should!). Will update my post

Comment: Got it figured out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should be fine. Also at what point in the html , would you make this check is important (for the url to contain "index.html") normally you can create a function doAfterLoad() and put a call to doAfterLoad() that can check for the url substring and then accordingly show/hide the homepage link. you can use html body onLoad event also.

ps: you dont need to follow $ prefix to a var in js even though its a valid var name:
$turnonhomelink==true